# React - Updating a single element within a loop

Tags: reactjs

In my React site have an array that I `.map()`, so looping through then for each element creating a 'Generate' button.

When a specific 'Generate' button is clicked, I would like only that single button to be updated. I thought I of using states at first, but having just one would effect all the buttons.

The only other way I can think of is setting an id, then searching the element with that id.

Any other suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: State will work fine, just use an array

Comment: Set an array of objects with ids, then in the generate function, just use the id to filter out or act on the id of the item in the state array.